# xcode swift UIWebview disable links to open that start with https://m

Tags: xcode, swift3, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Hey guys so intially im loading a https://www.etcccc link but its a video and it has an overlay image that if clicked it will navigate to a https://m.etccccc,,, I just need to restrict urls that start with a "m" instead of "www" to return a false in the shouldstartloadrequest but im having issues. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webview delegate shouldStartLoadWith request is best place to restrict the url.try this

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        if request.url?.host?.hasPrefix("m") == true{
         return false
        }
        else{
         return true
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem, I was approaching it in a different way by getting the url as an absolute string then separating it using "." but it was still giving me issues, this solved it! much appreciated!